# What is an easy way to parse a date Http Header in C?

Tags: c, http, parsing, email, date

I want to parse an email http date header, is there an easy way to do it without writing my own string parsing functions?

Example:

```
Date: Fri, 19 Mar 2010 11:44:02 -0700
```

To clarify, parsing out the `Date:` part is easy, im talking about the actual date string. Ideally, id like to get the epoch time.

Comment: Actually, it's not quite a duplicate since that question implies that the format isn't fixed - in this case it is .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's available in your target system (eg Linux) you can use [`strptime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime).

Comment: And if it's not, there are other options here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414155/c-library-for-parsing-date-time

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer? How does it help? The fact that you can use `strptime` does not help much, but finding the right set of parameters to `strptime` might be the actual answer.

Comment: The strptime format string is "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"

Answer (score 0):

[libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) has a function for that, too:

```
time_t curl_getdate(char *datestring, time_t *now );
```

If you don't want to link the whole library, you can just copy the code for that from here: https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/parsedate.c