# Convert 'Sat, 24 Nov 2018 00:34:57 GMT' with C to milliseconds

Tags: c, linux

Tried this, but returns NULL.

```
struct tm *t = getdate("Sat, 24 Nov 2018 00:34:57 GMT");
```

I need this to parse HTTP response header.

I believe the format of the date/time here is called RFC 7231.

Comment: Is the environment variable `DATEMSK` set to the path of a file that contains a conversion specification that matches that format? Whats the value of `getdate_err` after `getdate()` failed?

Answer (score 0):

`getdate` returns `NULL` on failure and stores the error code in the global variable `getdate_err`. The meanings of the various error codes can be found here: https://linux.die.net/man/3/getdate_err

The most common error is error code 1, "The DATEMSK environment variable is not defined, or its value is an empty string." For `getdate` to work on Linux it expects you to have a file containing the format of your `getdate` strings, and for the environmental variable `DATEMSK` to point to that file.

An easier approach is to use `strptime` as detailed in this answer: [What is an easy way to parse a date Http Header in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821779/what-is-an-easy-way-to-parse-a-date-http-header-in-c)