# Convert from yyyymmdd to Day, Month Date, Year

Tags: c, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C Program to find day of week given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054016/c-program-to-find-day-of-week-given-date)

I have a calendar file that gives dates as "20121027T190000" and I need to convert that to "Wednesday, October 27 2012, 1900". Is there a C function that computes the day of the week?

Comment: There is a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054016/c-program-to-find-day-of-week-given-date

Comment: For reference, this is an ISO 8601 format date/time.

Comment: Also related: [C Library for Parsing Date Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414155/c-library-for-parsing-date-time)

Comment: 27 october 2012 is a saturday.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the standard `localtime()` function converts from a `time_t` to a `struct tm` that includes the day of the week. To create a `time_t` value, you can use the `mktime()` function to convert from a `struct tm` to a `time_t` (you do not have to fill in the day of the week when using `mktime()`).

This might seem like a roundabout way to do this, but it's reasonably straightforward and uses standard library functions.