# How to convert date to integer like in excel?

Tags: c, date, int

We have date for example:

```
char date[100] = "04/05/1900";
```

In excel you can convert it to integer.
For example 04/05/1900 = 125.

There is a library or function in C that converts the date to an integer and vice versa?

This is for my program in University, task which I should make in C.

```
char date[100] = "04/05/1900";
int number = 125;
int convertDatoToInteger(date);
char convertIntegerToDate(number);
```

I expect the output of 04/05/1900 to be 125.
And the output of 125 to be 04/05/1900.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C Library for Parsing Date Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414155/c-library-for-parsing-date-time)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please notice that even if there wasn't a duplicate, it's still off-topic to ask for us to recommend a library. Take a look at  ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Finally, if it's homework for uni, your instructor probably wants you to manually parse the date, not to rely on a library.

Comment: [How to find leap year programatically in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220163/how-to-find-leap-year-programatically-in-c) isn't a solution but might get you started.

Comment: The usual way to do this sort of thing in C is to fill in a `struct tm` with your year, month, and day, then call the library function [`mktime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) (or maybe [`timegm`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/timegm)).  But the number this gives you counts seconds (not days), and since 1970-01-01, not 1899-12-01.  (Is that really the base date Excel uses?)  But I suppose you could divide by 86400, and add 25598...

Comment: If you do end up doing anything with `struct tm`, beware that its definitions of "year" and "month" are peculiar.  `tm_mon` is 0-based, and `tm_year` is 1900-based.  (But `tm_mday` is fine.)

Comment: Beware also that `struct tm` and `mktime()` (and `timegm()`) deal in dates *and times*, meaning that complications like time zones and daylight saving time come into play.  If you're only intereted in dates, it's generally safest to set `tm_hour` to 12, and `tm_min` and `tm_sec` to 0.  (Also set `tm_isdst` to 0 or -1.)

Comment: @Dmitry Flow Note Excel has a bug in dates.  Try `"02/28/1900"`. `"02/29/1900"`. `"03/01/1900"`.  [incorrectly considered 1900 to be a leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year_bug).  Do you want that buggy behavior too?