# convert date string to int

Tags: c

I can write a function to parse the string date, but I feel like I am re-inventing the wheel here. Is there a faster, perhaps built-in function in **C** to get from a string date of this format: 1/4/2000 to an easier to use int like 20000104?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I try write this in C

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. C uses two types of time (1) Calendar Time (seconds since epoch 1/1/1970 -- your `int`) and (2) Broken Down Time (`struct tm`)  which has `int` values for members `tm_sec, tm_min, tm_hour, tm_mday, tm_mon, tm_year, tm_wday, tm_yday & tm_isdst`)

Answer (score 0):

This will help: [C Library for Parsing Date Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414155/c-library-for-parsing-date-time)

You could use the POSIX standard `getdate`, as here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdate.html

You'd have to include `time.h`

Then declare `MY_TIME` for the output

You could do `getdate("1/4/2000");`, then pass that to `strftime(MY_TIME, sizeof(MY_TIME), "%Y%m%d", getdate("1/4/2000"))`, which formats it.

Note that `getdate()` is a **POSIX STANDARD** and is not supported on Visual C++